# Excel 2010 Macro to Find & Replace

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have multiple work sheets in one work book. The work sheets i'm concerned with are WD, Hit, Sam, Sea, and Max.
Each page uses the same exact template, so everything should match up...

Here's the question.
In certain cells of my main page (-Listings-), i have formulas to pull information from another page. I'd like to create a macro that read cell O1 and search A1:AA12 and replace it with the new sheet.
Example: Cell C9 has =(WD!B3) E9 has =(WD!C3) .....etc

Code i'm using

```
Sub FindNReplace1()
'
' FindNReplace Macro
'

'
Cells.Replace What:=O1, Replacement:="Sea", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

        Range("O1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sea"
End Sub
```

This changes my formulas over to the Seagate sheet.
I don't know how to only search certain ranges, so i'll need help with that too.

I figured i would use 5 Macros. One for each sheet name the formulas have to convert to. I know i don't have to add the extra part in my code to select O1 and put the name in it considering the find & replace would do that for me.

If the macros i use could switch as well, that would be great. That's prolly for another question but i'll add it in here as well.

I use these macros as buttons to change to the next piece of inventory to list on my log. They are set to go to the "WD" sheet, go to the next cell up/down, and go back to my inventory page. These are the only macros that will need to change along with the formulas on my listings page.

Up

```
Sub autoup()
'
' autoup Macro
'

'
Sheets("WD").Select
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Down

```
Sub autodown()
'
' autodown Macro
'

'
Sheets("WD").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

    Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets(1).Range("A1:AA12").Replace What:=Sheets(1).Range("O1"), Replacement:="Sea", LookAt:=xlPart` or shorter `[A1:AA12].Replace What:=[O1], Replacement:="Sea", LookAt:=xlPart`

Comment: idk what i'm doing wrong, but your stretch of code is glowing red. I added some to it.
`Sub FindNReplace66()

'
' FindNReplace66 Macro
'

'
Sheets(1).Range("A1:AA12").Replace What:=Sheets(1).Range("O1"), Replacement:="Sea", LookAt:=xlPart [A1:AA12].Replace What:=[O1], Replacement:="Sea", LookAt:=xlPart
End Sub`

Comment: http://ge.tt/9MEvUFL2/v/0?c

Comment: That worked perfectly for changing the formulas in A1:AA12. Is there a way to have it change a macro? The macro i use switches to the WD page, goes down one cell, and then back to -LISTINGS- page. Is there a way to have it go to which ever sheet the -LISTINGS- page is linked to?

Comment: Is that about your initial  second question? Those `autoup` and `autodown` macros? If yes, I do not understand your specific question

Comment: Yes, that is about the initial second question. Those two macros are assigned to an up and down arrow on the main sheet (-LISTINGS-) of the log i use. When clicked, they go to the WD sheet, go up/down to the next selected cell, and switch back to the -LISTINGS- page. I'd like the macro you made for me, and apply that to those two macros. This way, if i find and replace everything to "Sea", the up and down macro will then switch to the "Sea" sheet and back instead. Perhaps it can go to the last active sheet if changing a macro with a macro isnt possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26351/discussion-between-ryan-hubbard-and-nixda).

Comment: I actually figured out a way to remedy this. Instead i will create a macro up/down for each sheet. Then at the end of the first macro to Find & Replace i'll add `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 43")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "Sheets Up/Down macro name here."`

This will select the buttons and reassign them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems as though i've got the answer and i'd like to share it. Thanks to @nixda ad myself.

Here's my module 7. This changes the formulas and changes the up/down arrows on the page i use.

```
Sub FindAndReplaceWD()
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("A1:AA12").Replace What:=Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("O1"), Replacement:="WD", LookAt:=xlPart
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 42")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autoUpWD"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 43")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autodownWD"
End Sub

Sub FindAndReplaceSea()
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("A1:AA12").Replace What:=Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("O1"), Replacement:="Sea", LookAt:=xlPart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 42")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autoUpSea"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 43")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autodownSea"
End Sub

Sub FindAndReplaceHit()
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("A1:AA12").Replace What:=Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("O1"), Replacement:="Hit", LookAt:=xlPart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 42")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autoUpHit"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 43")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autodownHit"
End Sub

Sub FindAndReplaceSam()
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("A1:AA12").Replace What:=Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("O1"), Replacement:="Sam", LookAt:=xlPart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 42")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autoUpSam"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 43")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autodownSam"
End Sub

Sub FindAndReplaceMax()
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Range("A1:AA12").Replace What:=Sheets("-LISTINGS-   ").Range("O1"), Replacement:="Max", LookAt:=xlPart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 42")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autoUpMax"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 43")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "autodownMax"
End Sub

Sub autoupWD()
Sheets("WD").Select
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub autodownWD()
Sheets("WD").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

    Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub autoupSea()
Sheets("Sea").Select
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub autodownSea()
Sheets("Sea").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

    Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub autoupSam()
Sheets("Sam").Select
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub autodownSam()
Sheets("Sam").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

    Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub
Sub autoupMax()
Sheets("Max").Select
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub autodownMax()
Sheets("Max").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Sheets("-LISTINGS-").Select

    Range("H11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

 Range("F9").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

There's some extra in each up/down macro. That's to erase the contents of a certain cell, and copy the value of another.